# is it better to create separate request class for each new method in controller, or edit existing request class in laravel or any better idea?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

Is it better to create separate request class for each new method in controller or edit existing request class  in laravel or any better idea ?

example

```
 class fooBarController {

      public function a(fooBarARequest $r) {

      }

      public function b(fooBarBrequest $r) {

      }

      public function c(fooBarCDRequest $r) {

      }

      public function d(fooBarCDRequest $r) {

      } 
 }
```

Comment: What is the goal of your requests? Of what type are they (`GET`, `POST`, ...)?

Comment: **POST TYPE ALL REQUEST**

Answer (score 1):

Using extra request classes allows you to define validation rules which your request is checked against before it reaches your controller. You can also handle authorization in the request class. An example would be:

```
class UpdateAccountEmail extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // authorization is handled on route/middleware level
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'new_email'                 => 'required|email|confirmed',
            'new_email_confirmation'    => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

So, to sum it up: it does not make sense to use a custom request class for requests which do not have payload that needs to be validated. This means, for a normal `GET` request we most likely (of course there are exceptions) want to use the normal [`Request`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php) class provided by laravel. A controller like this would be quite normal:

```
class AccountController
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        return view('account.show', ['user' => $request->user()]);
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        return view('account.edit', ['user' => \Auth::user()]);
    }

    public function updateEmail(UpdateAccountEmail $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $user->email = $request->input('new_email');
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('account.index');
    }

    public function logins(Request $request)
    {
        $logins = $request->user()->logins()
            ->when($request->get('filter_from'), function ($query, $from) {
                $query->where('created_at', '>=', $from);
            })
            ->when($request->get('filter_until'), function ($query, $until) {
                $query->where('created_at', '<=', $until);
            })
            ->get();

        return view('account.logins', ['logins' => $logins]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, for the `GET` request that is handled by `logins(Request $request)`, we do not use a custom request class because we don't need to validate anything (well, we could validate the filter parameters, but for simplicity we don't).

The example above also shows different methods of retrieving the current user. Even for that you don't need a request at all.

*This is no actual production code, just something off the top of my head...*